# jquery datatables word wrap not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css, datatables-1.10

My datatable's column looks wider if the value is too long.

[image]

i have following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688919/jquery-datatables-columns-overflow) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23715018/how-to-give-word-wrap-break-word-property-to-a-datatable-column).
And setting the width :

```
aTable = $("#printdata").dataTable({
     "bAutoWidth" : false,
     "bRetrieve"  : true,
     "scrollY": 200,
     "scrollX": true,
     "deferRender": true,
     "scroller": {
          loadingIndicator: true
          },
     "bServerSide": true,
     "bProcessing": true,
     "sAjaxSource": 'show2ndsampling.php',
     "fnServerData": function (sSource,aoData,fnCallback){
          $.ajax({
                   "dataType":'json',
                   "type":'POST',
                   "url":sSource,
                   "data":aoData,
                   "success":function(json){
                          fnCallback(json);
                          }
                   });
          },
    "order"  : [[1,"desc"]],
    "aoColumns"  : [
    /*serial*/{ "width": "30%", target : 3 }
    ]
```

But there is no change in my datatable.

Comment: It means that you don't have spaces in your word. That's why this happens.

Comment: Word wrap is working when word have space.

Comment: Please post your full Datatables initialization code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do this

```css
table.dataTable tbody td {
  word-break: break-word;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qh63k1sg/**

This is implied that `autoWidth` is set to false and you have given the columns a fixed width (as in the demo and as OP have described he does with `aoColumns` / `columns`).

Answer (score 1):

For now, I can tell you, that the best way for displaying data is modifying your output.

It means:

1. if you create response on base of `sql query` -> you should optimize
   it and add a space in your quesry.
2. If you do it in template -> prepare data on templeate part, example on PHP
3. If you do it on frontend part, make it in JS way.

PHP way :

```
$result = array( /* your result */);
foreach($result as &$answer ){
   $answer = implode( ", ", explode( ",", $answer) );
}
```

JS way :

```
var result = [/* your result */];
for( var index = 0; index < result.length; i++ ){
  result[index] = result[index].split(",").join(", ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this with css.

```
table /* give class of table*/
{
   table-layout: fixed;
}

table td
{
  word-wrap:break-word;   
  overflow: hidden;
}
```